# How to use Collection in .net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to .net MVC 3. I am trying to render a collection. How do I map a collection to a model and and operate on it.

I am searching for a simple example of how to do this. If anyone has come across any examples of doing this, can you please send them to me so I can learn.

Thanks

Comment: what collection? in MVC the Controller passes the View a Model.  If the model has a property that is a List<T> or ICollection<T> then you can enumerate over it in the markup when you're rendering the view.  Does that make sense? I can offer a sample.

Comment: yes please.. sample would be helpful..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great example of how to iterate a collection in MVC 3

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx

Specifically you want to follow this pattern:

**Controller**

```
public class NamesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var names = new List<string>() { "Bob", "James", "Jim" };

        return View(names);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IList<string>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Names</h1>

        <ul>
            @foreach(var name in model) {
                <li>@name</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.. but how do i fill the list with values retrieved form DB?

Comment: What kind of database are you using and what will you be using to access that database with? If you're using MsSQL, you might want to look into Entity Framwork. Here is a link to a great video tutorial on how to get all this setup. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467